# Method working on emulator but not on an android phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, internet-connection

I have a function which returns **true** or **false** based on the internet availability:

```
 private boolean isNetworkAvailable(String url, int timeout) {
         try{
             URL myUrl = new URL(url);
             URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
             connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
             connection.connect();
             return true;
         } catch (Exception e) {
             return false;
         }
```

It's working right on the emulator but its returning false always on the android phone even if the internet is running on that phone!

Comment: plug your device into your machine and see what Log.v(url) says when you run the app on the devise in developer mode.

Comment: What Exception does it throw? Put Log.e("", "", e); in the catch block

Comment: Go for e.printStackTrace(); in catch and see what exception you are getting.

Comment: @Mr.Concolato thanx, i will do it!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should change "Exeption e" to "IOException e".
Then check where you call this method. You shouldn't call in in main thread.